# Distorted content while scrolling table in Safari browser

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, safari

[image]

My requirement is to have a table wherein all rows and table header can be scrollable as shown in the image above.

While scrolling any row or table header, whole table should scroll.

For this i am using javascript. Code can be seen here : [Github source code](https://github.com/primecoderIN/TableDemo/tree/master/src)

The problem is this works well in chrome, edge , firefox and opera.

When i open this page in safari in mac some distortions i see while scrolling. Scrolling is not smooth. See the page live here : [Scrollable table demo](https://sanjeevtest.netlify.app/)

Please let me know if you know why this is happening in safari and let me know the solution.